# Windows 10 installation winload.efi error

Tags: windows-10, 64-bit, uefi

I previously had installed Windows 10 Pro on my Acer laptop and dual boot it with Arch Linux. After finding out my Win 10 key requires Education edition, I downloaded Education edition and using Gparted formatted the HDD and ran Windows 10 setup using Bootable USB made through Rufus. But I only get below message.

[image: Error message]

Am I missing something? Laptop is 64bit and UEFI

Comment: You choose the wrong options in Rufus

Answer (score -3):

You need to go and buy a disk to install windows on your computer, windows 10 does not have an install disk. that doesn't matter, you don't need a windows 10 install disk, you can use a windows 7 one. It is illegal to pirate windows, so i don't recommend pirating it. I have windows 10, and the exact same thing happened to me. My friend had an install disk of windows 7, and i just put it in my PC and started it. That's how you can fix your problem, and it may take over an hour to fix it, but its way better than buying a new computer.

Comment: The user has a license key.  Installation disks for a windows 10 are free.

Comment: As Ramhound said, you can download the media creator from Microsoft and create boot devices for free, its the licence that costs you.